# IO cannot resolve

Tags: java, io

Hello guys im having problem with importing `java.io.*;` When i do this i cannot resolved `PrintStream`. I tried to import only `PrintStream` and the problem was the same. I readed articles here and at other places about changing my libraries, cleaning project, refreshing it but the problem is still there? Can someone help me?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Group {

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Student> students;

    public Group(String name){
        this.name = name;
        this.students = ArrayList<Student>();
        }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;

    }

    public ArrayList<Student> getStudents() {

        return this.students;

    }

    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        students.add(student);

    }

    public void printStudents(PrintStream output) {
        output.printf("Group name: %s%n", this.name);
        output.printf("Students in group:%n");
        for (Student student : this.students) {
            output.printf("  Name: %s%n", student.getName());

        }

    }

}
```

And in the end i still cannot resolve PrintStream to a type

Comment: `java.io*.;` check this again. Where did you put the `*`?

Comment: Maybe a typo? Try to use more copy-paste from JavaDoc

Comment: use java.io.* not io*.

Comment: Can you post a code example and give more details about the development environment?

Comment: using java 1.7.0_17 and Eclipse Platform

Version: 4.2.1.v20130118-173121-9MF7GHYdG0B5kx4E_SkfZV-1mNjVATf67ZAb7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
```

Should work.

Or, if you have another class named PrintStream in the same package :

```
public void printStudents( java.io.PrintStream output ) {
   ...
}
```

Ctrl-Shift-O in Eclipse.

Javadoc: [java.io.PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html)

Comment: i think the last thing worked to import the package at the same method